# efficiently trimming postgresql tables

Tags: postgresql, performance, foreign-keys

I have about 10 tables with over 2 million records and one with 30 million.  I would like to efficiently remove older data from each of these tables.

My general algorithm is:

- create a temp table for each large table and populate it with newer data
- truncate the original tables
- copy tmp data back to original tables using: "insert into originaltable (select * from tmp_table)"

However, the last step of copying the data back is taking longer than I'd like. I thought about deleting the original tables and making the temp tables "permanent", but I lose constraint/foreign key info.

If I delete from the tables directly, it takes much longer.  Given that I need to preserve all foreign keys and constraints, are there any faster ways of removing the older data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest process is likely to be exactly as you've outlined:

1. Copy new data into a temporary table
2. Drop indexes and foreign keys
3. Drop the old table
4. Copy the temporary table back to the old table name
5. Rebuild indexes and foreign keys.

[The Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/populate.html) has some suggestions on perfomance, too, that may or may not apply. Frankly, however, it is significantly quicker to drop a table than to drop millions of rows (since each delete is performed tuple by tuple) and it is significantly quicker to insert millions of rows into a table with no constraints or indexes (as each constraint must be checked and each index must be updated for each record insert; by removing all constraints, you limit this to a single build of the index and a single verification for the constraint).

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" solution for these problems typically involves partitioning your tables on the appropriate key, such that when you need to delete old data, you can simply drop a whole partition -- certainly the fastest deletion that you will ever get.

However, partitioning in PostgreSQL isn't as easy as some other databases -- you need to relocate data manually using triggers, and there are caveats (e.g. no global primary keys)

See the [PostgreSQL manual on Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html)